# My record is not inserting into database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to insert my data into database using Textbox, Sometime it inserts the data in only using Internet Explorer but not in Mozilla firefox.

It's strange.....

My data sometime gets uploaded but only using Internet Explorer and sometimes it stops working. Please help what's that mean?

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $(".update_button").click(function() {

    var boxval = $("#content").val();
    var dataString = 'content='+ boxval;

    if(boxval=='')
    {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "demo.jsp",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false
        });
    }
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form method="post" name="form" action="">
            <h3>What are you doing?</h3>
            <textarea name="content" id="content" ></textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" class="update_button" />
        </form>
    </div>

    <%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poststatus", "root", "1234");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from messages order by msg_id desc");
            while(rs.next()){
                String msg=rs.getString("msg");
    %>
            <ol id="update" class="timeline"><%=msg %></ol>
<%
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>  

</body>
</html>
```

and here is my `demo.jsp`:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>

<%
    String content=request.getParameter("content");
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poststatus", "root", "1234");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into messages(msg) values('"+content+"')");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

And yes, I can fetch my data from database ..as you could see my code. But i'm unable to insert data..

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!***

**EDITED:**

Here is my created table:

```
create database if not exists poststatus;
use poststatus;

create table messages(
    msg_id INT auto_increment,
    msg VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    primary key(msg_id)
);
```

Comment: get the ajax response by `success:` `failure:` and `console.log` it..

Comment: I did used... But it says nothing... :(

Comment: give response from the url back to ajax and also update the code what you tried with `$.ajax` call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update button that sends the AJAX request is also the form's submit button, so when you click it, it begins submitting the form, which navigates away from the current page, cutting off the code before it can run the AJAX request.

Modify the beginning of your click handler to:

```
$(".update_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Calling [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event will prevent the form from submitting, giving your AJAX function the chance to run.

---

Additionally, there is a serious problem in the Java code; because the value is inserted with string concatenation, it creates a blatant SQL injection vulnerability, and also will not work if someone innocently types an apostrophe. Change:

```
Statement st=con.createStatement();
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into messages(msg) values('"+content+"')");
```

to:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into messages(msg) values(?)");
st.setString(1, content);
int i = st.executeUpdate();
```